# Rails 3. Order by count of matches (many to many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, match

I have a many to many association between two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_works
  has_many :works, through: :user_works
end   

class UserWork < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :work
end    

class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_works
  has_many :users, through: :user_works
end
```

I have a filter by works, containing several works (ids).

My task is to filter users by works and order them by count of matches.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to group by works, and order by count

That's how to sort from less works to more:

```
User.joins(:works).group("user_works.user_id").order("COUNT(*)")
```

That's how to sort from more works to less:

```
User.joins(:works).group("user_works.user_id").order("COUNT(*) DESC")
```

**Upd.**
If you want to have some extra filtering just add where clause

```
User.joins(:works).where("user_works.work_id in #{filter_string}").group("user_works.user_id").order("COUNT(*) DESC")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have just added "where("user_works.work_id in #{filter_string}")" between "joins" and "group". It works!