# Sort Shops by their Product Count in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to order a list of Shops by the count of Products from within in each Shop. I have a join in the middle between Shop and Product which is Ownership. So my models look like:

shop.rb

```
has_many :ownerships
has_many :products, through: :ownerships
```

product.rb

```
has_many :ownerships
has_many :shops, through: :ownerships
```

ownership.rb

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :shop
```

How would I turn this query around to order the products by count?

```
@shops = Shop.all.includes(:products).where('products.id IS NOT NULL').references(:products).order(id :desc)
```

I've tried variations of `.group('id').order('count(*) DESC')` such as:

```
@shops = Shop.all.includes(:products).where('products.id IS NOT NULL').references(:products).group(:id).order('count(*) DESC')
```

But can't seem to get around errors like

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "products.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3. Order by count of matches (many to many)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834399/rails-3-order-by-count-of-matches-many-to-many)

Comment: The above is giving me the same PG::GroupingError. Using `Shop.all.sort_by { |s| s.products.count }`actually works, but is pretty slow.

Comment: Count of what? The number of unique products or the total inventory number of all products or even the count of a specific product?

Comment: Stores grouped in order by total number of unique products (descending).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out in case anyone runs into the same thing.

All of the answers / comments were super close, but in order to get the Stores sorted by which ones had the most products in descending order, I used:

```
@stores = Store.joins(:products).group('stores.id').order('count(products.id) desc')
```

In trying to find which Stores had the most products of a particular brand sorted in descending, I modified the above to use:

```
@stores = Store.joins(:products).group('stores.id').where( :products  => { :brand_id => @brand.id } ).order('count(products.brand_id) desc')
```

ActiveRecord FTW.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it on my site I think we this problem just because of PG group by please try this:

```
Shop.all.joins(:products).select('products.*').where.not(products: {id: nil}).references(:products).group('products.id')
```

Comment: This is so close, however, this seems to be ordering the products, not the instances, which is weird because it comes back like `#<Instance:0x007fe211333858` as the object header, but then the first attribute was `id: 520685` which was not a valid instance id, but a product id